# updating a value in a column of the table which has json value making the column null

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, stored-procedures

Below is my procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'%' PROCEDURE 'UpdateContactStatus'(IN contactId INT, IN email VARCHAR(50), IN isActive INT) BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl_contactdetails
    SET user_Details = JSON_REPLACE(user_Details,
                    CONCAT('$[', JSON_SEARCH(user_Details, 'one', contactId, NULL, '$[*].contact_id'), '].IsActive'),
                    CASE WHEN JSON_CONTAINS(user_Details, CAST(CONCAT('[{"Email":"', email, '"}]') AS JSON)) THEN isActive ELSE JSON_EXTRACT(user_Details, CONCAT('$[', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(user_Details, 'one', contactId, NULL, '$[*].contact_id'))), '].IsActive')) END)
    WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(user_Details, CAST(CONCAT('[{"Email":"', email, '"}]') AS JSON))
    AND contact_id = contactId; END
```

calling it as `call UpdateContactStatus(164,'Mahishmatiji@gmail.com', 0);`

Table: `tbl_contactdetails`

Columns:

```
contact_id (int AI PK),
contact_Email (varchar(50)),
user_Details (json)
```

Row in the table

```
'164', 'Gita@gmail.com', '[{\"city\": \"jbp\", \"Email\": \"Mahishmatiji@gmail.com\", \"country\": \"India\", \"IsActive\": 1, \"Last_Name\": \"Yadav\", \"First_Name\": \"Mahii\"}, {\"city\": \"GDR\", \"Email\": \"Rajubhaiya@gmail.com\", \"country\": \"India\", \"IsActive\": 1, \"Last_Name\": \"Patel\", \"First_Name\": \"Raju\"}]'
```

I want to update `isActive` column as 0 where `contact_id` is 164 and `Email` is Mahishmatiji@gmail.com in user_Details column in the `tbl_contactdetails` table.

Running this procedure is making the `user_Details` null instead of changing the value of `isActive` to 0 where the email match the array.

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Provide desired output with detailed explanations.

Comment: Trying to get all the rows in which Email match in user_Details json.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), especially #5 and #3.